# Does APA Style prescribe BC and AD or BCE and CE?

Tags: writing-style

Does APA Style prescribe BC and AD or BCE and CE? (I couldn't seem to find information about this in their style guides/manuals.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless this was changed after 2016 (e.g. in the 7th edition style manual), APA does not prescribe either version. The choice of format does not seem to be addressed in the 6th edition style manual, which should typically be interpreted as leaving the writer or journal the freedom to choose their preference. In this case there is also [direct confirmation](https://twitter.com/sTeamTraen/status/750376876279988225) (shown below) from the APA Style official Twitter account that either version is fine as far as the style is concerned.

[image: Twitter thread where APA Style confirms either format is fine]